# GIT: three different repositories with common files

Tags: git

I have a situation:

-I have written about 100 utility scripts sitting in a directory on my path. 
-I have two different local computers, each with the same directory and MANY of the same files, but not all (as some scripts are written for that specific machine's operating system).

I am trying to use a remote git repository to make it easier for me to develop/make changes to these scripts. For example, if I make a change to a script on computer A, I can save the changes to a branch, upload that branch to the remote repository with

```
git push
```

and, next time I log on to computer B, I can just call a

```
git pull
```

command to get the latest version of the directory of scripts. My thinking is that I would have one main remote branch, that had all the scripts for each computer, and then two other branches that were computer-specific (thus three repos). This plan is not working out, as I'm unable to figure out how to continually merge updates into the other repos. I'm running out of ideas and wondering if someone more experienced with git could help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can get away with just a single branch. As its only you that would be working on the repo.

First make your code changings in local box (A or B) and before committing the code do **stash** them using:

```
$ git stash
```

Then pull all the changes from the remote using:

```
$ git pull
```

Then pop all your latest changes on top of them

```
$git stash pop
```

Then follow the usual commiting and pushing process.

```
$ git add .

$ git commit -m "work from boxA"

$ git push origin master
```

All you have to remember is **stash**  your local code change, **pull** the remote repo and then **stash pop** your changes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: how would I avoid the inevitable problem that there are some files (or potentially versions of files) that I want to store in the repo that are ONLY for that specific computer?

Comment: add them to `gitignore` file.

Comment: Yea exactly! you would add those computer-specific files to `.gitignore` file. This is usual practise, for eg. If I have a api-key or something sensitive info in my project i wouldn't push it to public github repo right?