# How to resolve all merge conflicts in favor of the just-popped stash?

Tags: git

Suppose that upon running `git stash pop`, one gets a `CONFLICT` message (resulting from a failed auto-merging attempt).

Is there a quick way to tell `git` to resolve *all* conflicts in favor of the stash that was just popped?

EDIT: I just wrote the following script to test the two alternatives proposed.  It

1. creates a fresh git repo in the directory `/tmp/$1`, and `cd`s to it;
2. creates a first version of a file and commits it;
3. makes some changes to the file and stashes the file;
4. makes other changes to the file (including both conflicting and non-conflicting changes), and commits these changes; and finally
5. pops the stash

This sets the stage for comparing the two proposed methods.  Here's the script:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias gcommit='git commit -q --allow-empty-message -m ""'
alias gmerge='git merge -q --no-edit'

TESTDIR=/tmp/$1
rm -rf "$TESTDIR"
mkdir -p "$TESTDIR"
cd "$TESTDIR"

git init -q
touch chiasmus.txt
git add . && gcommit

cat <<EOF > chiasmus.txt
ask

what

...
EOF
gcommit -a

cat <<EOF > chiasmus.txt
ask
not
what
your country can do for you
...
EOF
git stash -q

cat <<EOF > chiasmus.txt
quote:
ask

what
you can do for your country
...
jfk
EOF
gcommit -a

git stash pop -q
```

Then I ran

```
% bash gittest.sh checkout
% bash gittest.sh merge

% cd /tmp/checkout
% git checkout --theirs $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U)

% cd /tmp/merge
% git reset -q --hard
% git merge -q --no-edit --squash -Xtheirs stash
Auto-merging chiasmus.txt
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested

% diff /tmp/{checkout,merge}/chiasmus.txt
0a1
> quote:
5a7
> jfk
```

Therefore, it looks like the "checkout" option does lose the non-conflicting changes.  As it happens, though, this option more closely matches what I was really after, namely, have `git pop` behave more closely to what I expect it to do: return me to where I was when I ran `git stash`, period.  No auto-merge, etc.  (IOW, my question, as asked, really did not accurately reflect what I was after.  It's as if [meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) read my mind somehow.)

Comment: Do you have git configured to use a merge tool like KDiff3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the merge yourself, instead of the stash pop.  The stash commit's named `stash`.

```
git merge --squash -Xtheirs stash
```

Comment: Thanks.  I decided to accept your answer because it more accurately matches what I actually asked for, even though, ironically, meagar's solution is closer to what I was *really* after...

Comment: Heh. Yeah, I noticed your unhappiness with my answer to the question you asked earlier.  I confess I think the two-command sequence I gave there satisfies what you asked for there exactly.  But if the low-level commands turn you off, you could also instead of meagar's answer skip the stash pop and `git checkout stash -- .` though that will leave any new files in your pulled commit still tracked.

Comment: still works, 9 years later ... Thanks for this post

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `git checkout --theirs <file>` for [each file in conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874862/229044):

```
git checkout --theirs `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`
```

Comment: But if there's a file with a mix of conflicting and non-conflicting local changes, this will drop the non-conflicting changes won't it?

Comment: No. `--diff-filter=U` will show only unmerged changes, that is, files marked as containing conflicts.

Comment: How does checking out the --theirs version preserve the non-conflicting change hunks in the --ours version?